# How many months I have to wait to place google ad in my site

Tags: google, google-adsense

How many months I have to wait to put google ad in my website, and my website is three month old. Now have visitors of about 5000+ unique visitors/month. My region is India, somebody told me that for Indian website must have six months old. Also I have an doubt whether the site age is calculated my domain creation date or from site release date.

Comment: i think the only age is meter is the age of a person who will receive money from ads.

Comment: No I think you are wrong

Answer (score 3):

<strike>I don't see anything in the [Adsense guidelines](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=48182&gsessionid=svj6TicfHcyj5YCI3yAPkA) that says the age a site has been active is a factor for when it can sign up for Adsense. So the answer would be zero months. You can sign up immediately.</strike>

Based on the link you provided in your content it appears you do have to wait six months due to be located in India. Google isn't clear on whether the six months is from the registration of the domain for the launch of the site. You should submit your site for inclusion at the six month anniversary of the registration date and if you are rejected try again at the six month anniversary date of the site launch.

Comment: They specify in their site "In some locations, including China and India, we require publishers to have owned their sites for 6 months."
http://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=9724&ctx=cb&cbid=-17a27e6m50n6&cbrank=2

Comment: In would be n ice if they included all of that information in one place instead of spread out like that. I never would have found that if you didn't link to it.

Comment: yes John Conde, Still I have confusion whether they are going find the domain age by whois record or from index date

Comment: Domain age would be by whois since that is the authoritative source. How long the site has been live would be by index date.

Comment: I know that difference.