# What are the minimum content and traffic requirements for Google AdSense?

Tags: google-adsense, website-design, blogger, google-adsense-policies

I have a blog which is only 35 days old. What are the requirements for Google AdSense?  How many page views are required and how old does the site have to be?

Answer (score 5):

Google requires that sites be up and running with a representative sample of content before they are approved for Google AdSense.

- At least 30 pages of content (for example 30 blog posts) with complete sentences and paragraphs
- Enough text content for content matching to work (not just images, videos, or Flash)
- No "under construction", "beta", or "coming soon" notices
- No blank pages or broken links
- Own your website for at least 6 months (required in some countries)

There are no minimum traffic requirements for your site at the time you sign up for AdSense.  However, it doesn't make sense to apply until you will be able to earn $100 which is the threshold at which you get paid.  A typical revenue per thousand pageviews (RPM) is $1.  So you need 100,000 page views to expect to make money with Google AdSense.

For more information, see Google's documentation: [Eligibility to participate in AdSense](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9724?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

None of those apply but the actual terms of services are long, complex and depend on the country where you are located.

The complete up to date terms are view-able directly on the Google [site](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms). Remember to select your country from the combo-box at the top. This is the country where you or your company gets bills, not the country of hosting which may be different or even distributed.

Comment: I don't think the OP was asking about the TOS. The other [answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/69612/94081) is more relevant IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Page views and the age of the blog are not required for Adsense.

Adsense simply gives you the option of placing Ads of different sizes on your webpage. Google will determine the relevance and type of ad based on the information on your page. For example, if you run a Tech blog, then expect most of the ads to be centered around technology and online services, as those relate to your content.

All you have to know is where you want to place the ads. Adsense will allow you to make unlimited ads, each of a different size. Sidebar ads are usually 300 pixels wide. Longer, skyscraper ads for thinner sidebars are 120 pixels wide and anything from 160 pixels to 720 pixels vertically. Header bars are thus 468 x 60 and 728 x 90 and so forth.

Comment: you say the age of the site is irrelevant but others say there is sometimes a minimum, like 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer by John Conde to [How many months I have to wait to place google ad in my site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13110/how-many-months-i-have-to-wait-to-place-google-ad-in-my-site/13111#13111):

> Based on the link you provided in your content it appears you do have
>   to wait six months due to be located in India. Google isn't clear on
>   whether the six months is from the registration of the domain for the
>   launch of the site. You should submit your site for inclusion at the
>   six month anniversary of the registration date and if you are rejected
>   try again at the six month anniversary date of the site launch.

Since the .in at the end of the [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) indicates the site is under India's country code, Google's [Eligibility to participate in AdSense](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9724?hl=en&ctx=cb&cbid=-17a27e6m50n6&cbrank=2) page states:

> In some locations, including China and India, we require publishers to
>   have owned their sites for 6 months. We've taken this step to ensure
>   the quality of our advertising network and protect the interests of
>   our advertisers and existing publishers.