# I have done all I can think of, but Google Adsense has rejected my site multiple times?

Tags: google-adsense, content, google-adsense-policies

My website has been rejected multiple times over the last year, and I can't seem to figure out the reason. I get about 1K users a month, with 19 posts on their own pages, a front page, privacy policy page, site map, about page, nav menus, search bar. My posts average at least a 1,000 words each. I thought I had done everything needed, but I get rejected each time.

> Your site isn’t ready to show ads
>
> error_outline Your site isn’t ready to show ads We’ve found some
> policy violations on your site which means your site isn’t ready to
> show ads yet.
>
> ***Low value content*** Your site does not yet meet the criteria of use in
> the Google publisher network. For more information, review the
> following resources:

Comment: I'm not sure what the policy violation is, but 20 posts is not usually enough.  See [What are the minimum content and traffic requirements for Google AdSense?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43211/what-are-the-minimum-content-and-traffic-requirements-for-google-adsense/69612#69612)

Comment: The policy violation was for "Thin Content".  I looked up this policy and none of my pages fit the descriptions for this policy.

Comment: They may mean "thin" as in "not enough."  It also doesn't really make sense to apply for AdSense until you are getting 100,000 page views each month.  That is about what you need get to the minimum payment threshold of $100.  Even with 10,000 page views per month, it would take about a year to get paid.