# why my blog on blogger keeps getting rejected by google adsense

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

i made my blog on blogger with a custom domain. i have 20 posts as well as relevant pages. my site URL is [www.dailysomtech.com](http://www.dailysomtech.com) i have applied for google adsense for three times and i keep getting rejected. they say the following:

1 Minimum content requirements
2 Make sure your site has unique high quality content and a good user experience
3 Webmaster quality guidelines for thin content
4 Webmaster quality guidelines
kindly assist me to correct this issues

Comment: The message already explains why you keep getting rejected. Increase the amount of content and make sure there is unique, high quality content and good user experience on your site.

Comment: Are you applying with just 20 pages? Even if you got accepted there's no way such a small site to get enough views to make $100 required for payment

Comment: See also: [What are the minimum content and traffic requirements for Google AdSense?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43211/what-are-the-minimum-content-and-traffic-requirements-for-google-adsense)